# Create Feature Using K-Nearest Neighbors

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, knn, nearest-neighbor

I'm relatively new to Python and Machine Learning, but I've been working on building out a predictive model for Mortgage prices. Where I'm struggling is using the K-Nearest Neighbor algorithm to create a feature.

Here's how I understand the mechanics of what I want to accomplish:

1. I have two data files: Mortgages Sold and Mortgages Listed
2. In both data files I have the same features (including Lat/Long).
3. I want to create a column in Mortgages Listed that represents the median price of the most closely related homes in the immediate area.
4. I'll use the methodology listed in 3 to create columns for 1-3 months, 4-6 months, 7-12 months.
5. Another column would be the trend of those three columns.

I've found something on KNN imputation, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

How do I go about executing this idea? Are there resources that I may have missed that would help?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "most closely related homes in the immediate area": do you only consider distance as your relation measure?

Comment: Hey Yuval. No, I think it has to be more expansive than that. A 1 bd and a 4 bd within feet of each other could have very different prices. My goal is to take into account multiple features, including distance, to find the most like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, from what I understand, you want to fit the KNN Model using Mortgages Sold data to predict the prices for Mortgages Listed data.
This is a classical KNN problem where you will need to find the nearest features vectors in Sold data for each feature vector in Listed data, and then take the median of those feature vectors.

- Consider there are n rows in Sold data, and the feature vectors for each row are X1,X2, ..., Xn and the corresponding prices are P1, P2, ..., Pn

  `X_train = [X1, X2, ..., Xn]`

  `y_train = [P1, P2, ..., Pn]`
- Note here that each Xi itself is a feature vector and the representative of ith row
- For now, consider that you want 5 closest rows in Sold data for each row in Listed data. So, a KNN model parameter here which might need to be optimised later is:

  `NUMBER_OF_NEIGHBOURS = 5`
- Now, the training code will look something like this:

  `from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier`

  `knn_model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=NUMBER_OF_NEIGHBOURS)`

  `knn_model.fit(X_train, y_train)`
- For prediction, consider there are m rows in Listed data, and the feature vectors for each row are F1, F2, ..., Fm. The corresponding median prices Z1, Z2, ..., Zm need to be determined.

  `X_test = [F1, F2, ..., Fm]`
- Note that the feature vectors in X_train and X_test should be vectorized using the same Vectorizer/Transformer. Read more about Vectorizers [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html).
- The prediction code will look something like this:

  `y_predicted = knn_model.predict(X_test)`
- Each element of this y_predicted list will contain (in this case) 5 closest prices from y_train. That is:

  `y_predicted = [(P11, P12, .., P15), (P21, P22, .., P25), .., (Pm1, Pm2, .., Pm5)]`
- For each jth element of y_predicted:

  `import numpy as np`

  `Zj = np.median(np.array([Pj1, Pj2, .., Pj5]))`
- Hence, in that way, you can find the median price Zj for each row of Listed data
- Now, coming to the parameter optimisation part. The only hyper-parameter in your KNN Model would be NUMBER_OF_NEIGHBOURS. You can find the optimal value of this parameter by dividing the X_train itself into say 80:20 ratio. Train on the 80% part and cross-validate on the remaining 20% part. Once, you are sure that the accuracy numbers are good enough, you can use this value of the hyper-parameter NUMBER_OF_NEIGHBOURS for prediction on the y_test.
- In the end, for month-wise analysis, you will need to create month-wise models. For example, M1 = Trained on 1-3 month Sold data, M2 = Trained on 4-6 month Sold data, M3 = Trained on 7-12 month Sold data, etc.

Reference: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html